# words and sentences disorganization in last version of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, utf

I have Menus in my html code , I don't have problem with chrome and other web browsers until last update of google chrome to 38.0.2125 that cause disorganization in my menus and other parts (utf-8 encoding).

this is an exapmle of this problem :

http://cld.persiangig.com/preview/TLOA12gK5C/ex.jpg

any help ?!

Comment: Your element is too narrow, so the text is wrapping.

Comment: no it's not , you can't figure out ,because it's occur just in languages like Persian or Arabic !

Comment: You might need to add some codes to the question, so that others could understand what is really going on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to solve this problem use code below in your style of tag that contain your text or your body :

```
 body{
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

or

```
.yourTagClassName{
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

for more information see [this link](http://gilad.ir/tag/chrome-version-38-0-problem-in-menu/)